# Codeigniter URLs showing 404

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, codeigniter-url

I have a simple web hosting platform . I am hosting a Codeigniter application on /var/www/html
meaning this is the file structure :

```
html 
|-application
|---controllers
|---models
|---views
|---config
|-public
|-system
|-index.php
|-.htacess
```

My .htaccess file looks like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In my config.php file I have default root view controller as :

```
$config['base_url']     = 'http://www.example.com/';
```

While in my routes.php file , I have

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home"
```

So, naturally when I open www.mysite.com in my browser I get home/index automatically. But when I try any other URL like

```
www.example.com/home
www.example.com/home/index
www.example.com/admin
```

I get a 404 error. This is also noticeable that this folder was working perfectly on my local machine and one other remote server that I tried.

To be more precise, when I try www.example.com/home I get this error

```
Not Found
The requested URL /home was not found on this server.
```

### EDIT

My home controller looks like this .

```
class Home extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('home_view');
   }

    public function someFunction(){
       echo 'In some function';
    }

}
```

### EDIT

I dont if that helps but adding index.php to the URLs seems to open up the pages as expected. So

```
www.example.com/controller/function (DOES NOT WORK)
www.example.com/index.php/controller/function (WORKS)
```

Any help please?

Comment: please add more code of your Controller so that we can see more information.

Comment: Its a pretty simple controller. I have added the code . Please see Edit.

Comment: Have you tried adding RewriteBase / after RewriteEngine on?

Comment: Yes its readable and uploaded on the server. There are no recent error logs pertaining to this issue.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the action for different urls in the route file.
Like for site.com/search, add this before $route['default_controller'] = "home",

```
$route['search'] = "home/search"
```

What this means is, you will create a function search in your home controller which will load the view files for specified url.

Comment: Hmmm I am pretty sure thats not the solution as moving forward I might have 100 dynamic links and functions and I dont want to add route for each of them. If the same folder was working on another remote server, there has to be some other explanation for this.

Comment: Dude, you didnt mention you had 100 dynamic links earlier. In any case, this is not a wrong solution to get downvoted.
The solution to create dynamic links is similar, you just modify your route to this,
$route['search/(:query)'] = "home/search/$1";
and create a parameter in your search function of home controller.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Avinsh. I still think that this isnt the right way to go about solving this problem as this is a more generic problem. 
PS : My reputation is below 100 so I cant downvote. Someone else who thinks that this is not the right way to solve this problem might have downvoted :)

Comment: No issues Waris! I worked on a project based on codeigniter a few months back. Here are my settings if they are of any use to you,
config.php :
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

.htaccess:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]